# Add an external file to a makefile

Tags: c++, makefile

I am fairly new to *makefiles* and to stack overflow for that matter. I was wondering if there was a way of adding a file from another directory to a *makefile*

Here's an example of what I want to do:

File tree:

```
Software
  |____Lab_1
  |     |____hola.cpp
  |     |____hola.hpp
  |     |____hola.o
  |
  |___Lab_2
        |____hey.cpp
        |____hey.hpp
        |____main.cpp
        |____makefile
```

My makefile currently looks like this:

```
INC_DIR = ../Lab_1

all: hola.o hey.o main.o
    g++ hola.o hey.o main.o -o prog

point.o: hola.cpp hola.hpp
    g++ -c hola.cpp

hey.o: hey.cpp hey.hpp
    g++ -c hey.cpp

main.o: main.cpp
    g++ -c main.cpp
```

I want to use the contents of Lab_1 in the makefile I have in Lab_2, is there any way to do this?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: `INC_DIR = ../Lab_1` probably doesn't do what you want. What are the concrete problems you're facing? [Elaborate](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53619264/edit) please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put your Makefile under the `Software` directory and use variables, functions, implicit rules and dependencies auto-generation to simplify your task:

```
TARGET := prog
SOURCE := $(wildcard Lab_1/*.cpp) $(wildcard Lab_2/*.cpp)
OBJECT := $(SOURCE:.cpp=.o)
DEPEND := $(OBJECT:.o=.d)

CPPFLAGS := -MMD -MP -ILab_1

.PHONY: all

all: $(TARGET)

$(TARGET): $(OBJECT)
    $(CXX) -o $@ $^

-include $(DEPEND)
```

---

You're a beginner so you need to learn more to understand everything but here is the gist of it:

- The [`wildcard`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/File-Name-Functions.html#index-wildcard_002c-function) function will list all files with extension `.cpp` in both your `Lab` directories. `SOURCE` will contain `Lab_1/hola.cpp Lab_2/hey.cpp Lab_2/main.cpp` ;
- The `OBJECT` contains the same thing but with the extension replaced to `.o` ;
- The `DEPEND` contains the same thing but with the extension replaced to `.d` ;
- The `CPPFLAGS` variable contains the flag used by the preprocessor. The `-MMD -MP` flags instructs `g++` (contained in `$(CXX)`) to generate the `.d` files (dependencies files) and the `-include` instruction will include them if they exist in the filesystem ;
- The `$@` and `$^` are [automatic variables](https://www.gnu.org/s/make/manual/html_node/Automatic-Variables.html) ; in this context, `$@ = $(TARGET)` and `$^ = $(OBJECT)`.